# How do I create a clickable map where clicking on a specific part of the map takes you to a webpage using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, web-mapping, qgis2web

I have a shapefile of regions in Italy. I am creating a travel blog and I want to create a clickable map where when you click one of the regions it takes you to the relevant page for that region. Is there anyway to do this using QGIS? I am also using wix to create the website and I can code in Python if that helps.

Something similar to what is shown [here](https://www.spotzi.com/en/help-center/how-to-import-a-shapefile-into-qgis/) is what I need. You can see for example if you click on the US it takes you to another page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `CMS` like `WIX`, there are a lot of `javascript` libraries that you can use to implement your map fast and easily. For example, `amchart` has a [map component](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/#maps) that can be implement using `js` and you can add **click** and **hover** event to the map. If you are not familiar with this, just take a look at its demos.

If you need something more powerful, you can use `leaflet` to display a map and add some different layers on a based map like `open street map` **outdoor** layer which is good for your application. [This is an example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) of `leaflet`.

Comment: Right I see I'll look into these. So is there no way to do this using QGIS and something like qgis2web? Never done much with javascript before so just searching for the easiest solution.

Comment: I know what you mean but I'm not sure about QGIS and qgis2web function.

Answer (score 1):

With qgis2web export leaflet you can create a nice map.
But I think, a directly link is not possible.
However you need for all regions informations, for example the name of a region. And in addition you can insert  hyperlinks to other internet pages. This ist not a problem, because you can insert html within the table.
For example:
If you insert https://www.berlin.de you can see the clickable link "berlin.de" within the popup of the region/polygon. Now it open a new tab in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifically looking for a clickable united states map, then you can use the free code at https://clickablemapmaker.com/